# SQl connection to XAMP

Tags: mysql, connectivity

i am trying to connect my database to XAMP . I got  this error

Warning: Use of undefined constant ID - assumed 'ID' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Thairis\login.php on line 8

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Thairis\connectdb.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Thairis\login.php(11): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Thairis\connectdb.php on line 27

Answer (score 0):

mysql_* functions

- **officially [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** as of PHP 5.5 (released June 2013).
- **[removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql) entirely** as of PHP 7.0 (released December 2015)

So switch to 
[mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and use [always prepared statements with parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) because of sql injections

see [api comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)